# Animating a line between two Point objects

Tags: java, animation

What's the simplest way to draw a line between two Point objects in a way
that will look like I am drawing that line in real time by hand?

For example:

```
Point a = new Point(5,20);
Point b = new Point(15,20);
```

How do I connect these points with a "moving" line?

In other words I want to make the user feel "motion" of some sort. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Another time-warp from the mid-90's when people spelled Java as JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the answer by Chinmay Kanchi, you need to create a feeling of animation. As mentioned above in comments by Uhlen you should use Swing's Timer when working on EDT. To give you example of how to use Timer. Lets assume we have a panel and we want it to slide open on e.g. a button click, thus we need to animate it sliding open by increasing its size. Below is an example showing pretty much how you would use Timer to do the operations.

```
this.extendingTimer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       //assume sliding is vertical     
       int value = maximumHeight;
       //make sure the size will not be bigger then allowed maximum
       if(currentExtensionSize + extensionRate >= value)
       {
          currentExtensionSize = value;
          stopExtending();
       }
       else
          currentExtensionSize += extensionRate;
       setSize(new Dimension(maximumWidth, currentExtensionSize));
    }
});
extendingTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
extendingTimer.setDelay(100);
extendingTimer.setRepeats(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I don't mean to be greedy or anything but could you also give me a clue on how I would go about it when trying to gradually fill an Ellipse2D object with color using the Graphics2D class..?

Comment: This is a different and slightly harder problem. You'd need to determine the direction of the animation and the set of all the points inside the ellipse. You need to find all the points that satisfy the inequality `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 < 1` and draw points/lines according to how you want to fill it. If you need more detail, ask it as a different question.

Comment: Thanks..but it's getting way too complicated!All I needed were a couple of effects in my App but instead I find it extremely difficult to make even the slightest movement when it comes to swing..! The timer class is also very inconvenient due to the it works as it won't "allow" me to call a method with arguments..!

Comment: Heh, this is one reason I really dislike writing GUIs. If I must, I'll usually bang one up in HTML/JS. Certainly, the absence of a gui-configuration mini-language (like an XML file, as in wxWidgets) is a bit annoying.

Comment: Follow-up question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031542/filling-up-gradually-ellispe2d-objects-with-color-java-animation

Answer (score 4):

Given two points, you can determine the equation of the line connecting them. The equation of a line is of the form `y = mx + c`, where m is the slope, and c is the y intercept.

So, given your two points (5,20) and (15,20), we first determine m.

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
  = (20-20)/(15-5)
  = (0)/10
  = 0
```

Substituting into the equation for a straight line, we get `y = 0x + c` or `y = c`. Now that we know this, we simply need to know the points where y = c and 5<=x<=15. Simply draw each of these points in the normal way (look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/examples/ShapesDemo2D.java) for the exact method) with a `Thread.sleep()` call in between drawing each point. In this case, you have only 11 points to draw, so it would make sense to draw 1 point every 100 ms. For details on `Thread.sleep()` see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.html).

EDIT: Since `Thread.sleep()` won't work on the EDT, look at [javax.swing.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead, as Uhlen suggested.

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to use it..?

Answer (score 0):

```
int lineCount = 0; //global
// timer calls the below

xLocation = (*a)[a->size()-1] * timeSoFar / duration ;
    if(xLocation > (*a)[lineCount+1]){
        lineCount++;        
    }
    double m = ((*b)[lineCount+1] - (*b)[lineCount])/((*a)[lineCount+1]-(*a)[lineCount]);
    double yIntercept = (*b)[lineCount]-m*(*a)[lineCount];
    yLocation = m * xLocation + yIntercept;
    xLocation = (yLocation - yIntercept) / m;
```

this is in c++ and using vectors but its the theory we want. This allows for multiple lines not just one.