# Animating an object to move between two points

Tags: java, animation

I'm making a game where you have to order troops around, meaning click on the destination, click on the soldier, and the soldier moves to the destination.

I am having problems with the animation part.  I have already figured out the MouseListener and graphics stuff. I know that you are supposed to use `y = mx + b`, `m = y2 - y1/x2 - x1` and `y - y1 = m(x - x1)`, but don't know how to implement this into my application.

I have a `Game` class that contains the listeners, and a `UserUnit` class that contains the actual `moveTo()` method. Assume that I've got everything else figured out, if I don't I'll ask. Thanks.

Comment: Is there something specific you are having trouble with (i.e. running into errors or something not working as expected) or are you looking for design suggestions?  You will probably have to ask more targeted/specific questions if you want to get much help here.

Comment: Maybe explain what you've tried so far and at what point you're getting stumped.

Comment: I think that is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010097/animating-a-line-between-two-point-objects

Answer (score 1):

In this related [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/), robots [`move(int, int)`](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.html#move%28int,%20int%29) toward the player's grid position by stepping in one of eight (semi-) cardinal directions, as shown [here](http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.java?revision=65&view=markup). An instance of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) drives the animation.