# Collision detection using plain arrays and rectangles--java

Tags: java, arrays, collision-detection

I am almost done with my first little java game for my final project.  It is a sidescroller where you have to shoot/avoid asteroids. My last problem is figuring out how to make my array of asteroids collide with the player's lasers.  Here's what I have so far, there's an "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" on line 137, that I can't deal with.  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: I added in my other classes, I realize it would be hard to judge the functionality of my code if I didn't show you where it came from.

```
package ShooterGame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{   
    Enemy[] baddies = new Enemy[10000];
    Player p;
    Image img;
    int y;
    Timer time;
    boolean lost = false;
    static Font font = new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 24);
    public AudioClip theme, bang, laser;    
    static ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;

    public static int score = 0;
    public static int lives = 5;

    public Board() 
    {           
        p = new Player();       
        addKeyListener(new ActionListener());
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("images/background.png");
        img = i.getImage();

        time = new Timer(5, this);
        time.start();

        for(int j = 0; j < baddies.length; j++)
        {   
            Random ran = new Random();
            y = ran.nextInt(365)+1;
            baddies[j]= new Enemy((100*j + 700), y, "images/asteroid.gif");
        }

        theme = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("theme.mid"));
        theme.play();

        bang = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("bang.wav"));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        checkCollisions();
        ArrayList<?> bullets = Player.getBullets();

        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            Bullet b = (Bullet)bullets.get(i);

            if(b.isVisible() == true)
            {
                b.move();
            }
            else
            {
                bullets.remove(i);
            }
        }

        p.move();
        for(int i = 0; i < baddies.length; i++)
        {
            if(p.x > 400)
            {
                baddies[i].move(p.getdx());
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        if(lost)
        {
            g2d.drawString("You Lose!", 300, 300);
        }

        if((p.getX() - 590) % 2400 == 0 || (p.getX() - 590) % 2400 == 1)
        {
            p.nx = 0;
        }

        if((p.getX() - 1790) % 2400 == 0 ||(p.getX() - 1790) % 2400 == 1)
        {
            p.nx2 = 0;
        }

        g2d.drawImage(img, 685-p.nx2, 0, null);

        if(p.getX() >= 590)
        {
            g2d.drawImage(img, 685-p.nx, 0, null);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.edge, p.getY(), null);

        ArrayList<?> bullets = Player.getBullets();
        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            Bullet b = (Bullet)bullets.get(i);
            g2d.drawImage(b.getImg(), b.getX(), b.getY(), null);

        }
            for(int i = 0; i < baddies.length; i++)
            {
                if(baddies[i].isAlive == true)
                {
                    g2d.drawImage(baddies[i].getImg(), baddies[i].getX(), baddies[i].getY(), null);
                }
            }

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawString("Score: " + score, 0, 320);
        g2d.drawString("Lives: " + lives, 80, 320);
    }

    public void checkCollisions()
    {       
        Rectangle[] rect = new Rectangle[baddies.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < baddies.length; i++)
        {
            Enemy e = (Enemy)baddies[i];
            rect[i] = e.getBounds();
        }

        ArrayList<?> bullets = Player.getBullets();
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            Bullet b = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
            Rectangle b1 = b.getBounds();

            if (rect[i].intersects(b1) && baddies[i].isAlive())
            {
                score++;
                baddies[i].isAlive = false;
                baddies[i].isVisible = false;
                bang.play();
             }

            Rectangle h = p.getBounds();
            if (h.intersects(rect[i]))
            {
                if(baddies[i].isAlive() == true)
                {
                    lives--;
                    if(lives < 0)
                    {
                        lost = true;
                        theme.stop();
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ActionListener extends KeyAdapter
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            p.keyReleased(e);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            p.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy

```
package ShooterGame;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Enemy 
{
    int x, y;
    Image img;
    boolean isAlive = true;
    boolean isVisible = true;


    public Enemy(int startX, int startY, String location)
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        ImageIcon l = new ImageIcon(location);
        img = l.getImage();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 60, 60);
    }


    public int getX() 
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() 
    {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() 
    {
        return isAlive;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() 
    {
        return isVisible;
    }

    public Image getImg() 
    {
        return img;
    }   

    public void move(int dx)
    {
        x = x - dx;
    }

}
```

Bullet

```
package ShooterGame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class Bullet 
{   
    int x, y;
    Image img;
    boolean visible;

    public Bullet(int startX, int startY)
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;

        ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon("images/bullet.gif");
        img = newBullet.getImage();
        visible = true;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 9, 5);
    }

    public int getX() 
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() 
    {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImg() 
    {
        return img;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() 
    {
        return visible;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        x = x + 2;
        if(x > 700)
        {
            visible = false;
        }
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean isVisible)
    {
        visible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

Player

```
package ShooterGame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player 
{

    int x, dx, y, dy, nx2, nx, edge, ceiling; 
    Image player;
    ImageIcon ib = new ImageIcon("images/player1back.gif");
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("images/playerstill.gif");
    ImageIcon f = new ImageIcon("images/playerforward.gif");
    ImageIcon up = new ImageIcon("images/playerup.gif");
    ImageIcon down = new ImageIcon("images/playerdown.gif");
    public AudioClip laser;
    static ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;

    public Player()
    {laser = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("laser.wav"));
        player = ib.getImage();
        x = 75;
        nx = 0;
        nx2 = 685;
        y = 172;
        edge = 150;
        ceiling = 0;
        bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    }

    public static ArrayList<Bullet> getBullets()
    {
        return bullets;
    }

    public void fire()
    {
        Bullet z = new Bullet((edge + 60), (y+17));
        bullets.add(z); 
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(edge, y, 43, 39);
    }

    public void move()
    {
        y = y + dy;
        if(y < ceiling)
        {
            y = ceiling;
        }

        if(y > 290)
        {
            y = 290;
        }

        if(dx != -1)
        {
            if(edge + dx <= 151)
            {
                edge = edge + dx;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x + dx;
                nx2 = nx2 + dx;
                nx = nx + dx;
            }
        }
        else
            {
            if(edge + dx > 0)
            {
                edge = edge + dx;
            }
        }   

    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getdx()
    {
        return dx;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage()
    {
        return player;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            dx = 2;
            player = f.getImage();
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            dy = -1;
            player = up.getImage();
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            dy = 1;
            player = down.getImage();
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            fire();
            laser.play();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            dx = 1;
            player = ib.getImage();
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            dy = 0;
            player = ib.getImage();
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            dy = 0;
            player = ib.getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Frame

```
package ShooterGame;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame 
{
    public AudioClip theme;

        public Frame()
        {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Board());
                frame.setTitle("SideShooter");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(700,365);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                new Frame();

        }
}
```

Comment: @Krroae27  *"homework questions aren't loved."*  Please speak for yourself when making such statements.  The [tag:homework] tag has *many* followers.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag for me, Andrew. I think it is fair to ask about one thing I didn't learn in class. I went way off template for this assignment.

Comment: I notice you check if a baddie is alive alot, do you need a record of it after it is dead? You might find it easier to just remove them completely after they are dead

Comment: *"I think it is fair to ask about one thing I didn't learn in class."*  ..or a 100.  Why stop at 1? :) *"I went way off template for this assignment."*  Good work.  But be careful not to throw in too much that you'll still be debugging core functionality as the deadline approaches.  As it is I can see a potential problem in accessing the images by `String` - that will come back to bite you in the a** later.

Comment: I don't need a record of it after it is dead, but I'm not sure how to remove objects from an array, for some reason it seems different than removing a String or char.

And thanks Andrew, the deadline is actually tomorrow, and as of right now, this is the last thing I have to make work.

Comment: Be sure to start comments with @dann.dev so the person will be notified.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks again.  I think the String will be fine as long as I keep the images in the project folder where they are currently living.

Comment: @Ryan if we are still looking for the null pointer (not sure it seems like the conversation has moved on since then) can you pust the **full** staktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the line

```
rect[i] = e.getBounds();
```

Are you not initializing the bounds of your `Enemy` class correctly? Alternatively, the Enemy you pulled out of the array could be null.

Comment: It initialized before, when I was using just one enemy dubbed Enemy e1. So I think the getBounds() method works, i don't think think casting worked, nor do I really know how to use the Rectangle array correctly.

Comment: @Ryan If the error is on the `rect[i] = e.getBounds();` then that means e is null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is the line mentioned in the other answer, but I believe it is that all the enemies may not be initialised before it checks collisions. Because you are making 10000 of them to start with, I think your action performed method may be checking collisions before they have all be created.

One thing to try could be to bring down the amount of enemies you have and see if it still keeps happening, try 100 or 1000, but this still won't fix the issue.

You really want to be change your game to run in it's own loop though, at the moment you are only checking collisions when the player performs an action. so if the player stops moving, no collision detection...

I would suggest that you find a book called 'Killer Game Programming in Java', there are free ebook version, and just read the first 2 chapters about making a game loop. The book is a bit old, but the basics of the loop are very good.

This [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439788/trying-to-move-an-object-from-a-fixed-starting-point-to-the-coordinates-of-a-mou/8440066#8440066) also contains a very simple loop, and some suggestions in the comments about how to make it better.